# H1 as an inline element

Tags: seo

If I use H1 as an inline element (since it fits the design better) will it be treated the same by the SE crawlers, or will it hurt its effectiveness?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 5):

It will be treated the same. Custom design is not black hat SEO.

Comment: Even if the element is hidden?